# Property 'center' not found on object of type UIImage *

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, quartz-core

I have a defined a view on my controller called FirstView. I have this in my -(void)move method:

```
-(void)move
{
 head = CGPointMake(head.center.x + X, head.center.y + Y);
}
```

I have already defined X and Y as integers and 'head' as a UIImage in my .h file. I get the error 'Property 'center' not found on object of type UIImage *' for the above line of code. Is there any way to change or cast this to UIImageView? I want to have UIImage because I am doing animations and drawing images on the view that I have defined. Quartzcore allows only UIImage and not UIImageView. So, what am I missing here?

Comment: A UIImage doesn't have center because it isn't a view. The UIMageView has a center. This is the view where a UIImage object is draw.

Comment: Right, so how do I change it? Like I said I want to draw something on my view using Quartzcore. I have done that using UIImage.

Comment: If you want draw with Quartz ( Core Graphics) you need use CGImageRef, create and context, move,... and work with C function: CGContextDrawImage ( CGContextRef c, CGRect rect, CGImageRef image )

Comment: Oh. I have drawn something like this:  CGPoint imgPt = CGPointMake(-1, 0);
    [image drawAtPoint:imgPt]; The errors that I describe are associated with drawAtPoint and drawRect

Comment: the `UIImage` is not a subset of `UIView`, therefore there is no such property for it. you cannot just 're-cast' it to `UIImageView` you have to instantiate an `UIImageView` object property.

Comment: Ok, that must work if you have a current context. You catch it with UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

Answer (score 0):

It's not found because it's not there!! Center, bounds, and frame is only for views. Any animation you want can be done with using UIImageView so whatever you are trying to do above is not the right way. So, I would suggest reading https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html

Comment: I actually created an Obj-C class that was a subclass of UIView so that it has the drawRect method which allows us to draw animations. Do I have to change the subclass to UIViewController or something like that and then change the image type to UIImage View?

Answer (score 0):

A `UIImage` doesn't have a center property because it's not a view. Use `UIImageView` and access it's `image` property to set it's image.

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView is derived from UIView so it has a center property while UIImage references to the image content so it doesn't have a center property. Instead of UIImage put UIImageView object there.

Comment: Oh. I have drawn something like this: CGPoint imgPt = CGPointMake(-1, 0); [image drawAtPoint:imgPt]; When I put a UIImage view object. I get 'no visible @interface for UIImageView declares the selector drawAtPoint'. The errors that I described are associated with drawAtPoint and drawRect